# Not able to Send Data from view to Api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Im trying to send JSON data to the Api controller where HttpPost can add that data to file.

JSON File:

```
{
"students": 
 [
  {
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Ravi",
  "Department": "IT"
},
{
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "Raj",
  "Department": "hr"
},
{
  "Id": 3,
  "Name": "avi",
  "Department": "it"
},
{
  "Id": 0,
  "Name": "string",
  "Department": "string"
},
{
  "Id": 8,
  "Name": "tanmay",
  "Department": "SDE"
},
{
  "Id": 10,
  "Name": "test",
  "Department": "Dev"
},
{
  "Id": 78,
  "Name": "abhi",
  "Department": "IT"
},
{
  "Id": 42,
  "Name": "grgr",
  "Department": "grgsrgs"
},
{
  "Id": 32,
  "Name": "wer",
  "Department": "new"
},
{
  "Id": 450,
  "Name": "tan",
  "Department": "ted"
}
]}
```

CLass:
public class Student
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

```
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
  public class Students
{
    public List<Student> students { get; set; }
}
```

API controller

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StudentsController : ControllerBase
{
    public List<Student> students { get; set; }

 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddUser(Students _Student)
    {

        var filePath = @"C:/Users/tanmay_pawar/source/repos/CRUDAPI/CRUDAPI/output.json";
        var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        Students students = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Students>(json);

        students.students.AddRange(_Student.students);

        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(students);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);

        return Ok();
    }
    }
```

jQuery:

```
     oStudent =
{
    "students": [   
    {
        Id: $("#st-Id").val(),
        Name: $("#st-Name").val(),
        Department: $("#st-Department").val()
        }
    ]
 }   


var postApiUrl = "https://localhost:7018/api/Students"

$.ajax({
    url: postApiUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(oStudent.students),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
 });
```

I want send data from view to my api controller so that api can add that data to my file.

my api is working fine but there is some issue with ajax because it is not sending data to my api.

Comment: Your code is making a POST request to a hard-coded absolute *local* URL that is almost certainly wrong. This will never work in production anyway, unless the browser runs on the same machine as the server. Use a *relative* URL instead

Comment: There seems mistake in preparing your JSON object:
 oStudent =
{
    "students": [   
    {
        Id: $("#st-Id").val(),
        Name: $("#st-Name").val(),
        Department: $("#st-Department").val()
        }
    ]
 }  
You are using "#" which means Id and it will only pick same or first input element values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your HTML structure, but you may just try this to check if your AJAX post call is sending data correctly.

Initialize JSON data variable like this:

```
var data = [{ "Id": "1", "Name": "Student name 1","Department":"Dept 1"},
              { "Id": "2", "Name": "Student name 2","Department":"Dept 2"}
];
```

Call make AJAX call:

```
var postApiUrl = "/api/Students";

$.ajax({
    url: postApiUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
 });
```

> In your javascript you are also missing ";" semi-colon on the line
> where you are providng URL.

Comment: Ajax post call is not sending data.

Comment: tried but ajax is not calling to api

Comment: you are also missing method name in your api call. Change it from 
var postApiUrl = "/api/Students";
to 
var postApiUrl = "/api/Students/AddUser";

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use 'JSON.stringify' in data variable, update your url like this:

```
var postApiUrl = "https://localhost:7018/api/Students/AddUser";


$.ajax({
    url: postApiUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        Id: $("#st-Id").val(),
        Name: $("#st-Name").val(),
        Department: $("#st-Department").val()
        },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
 });
```

also this code provides a cleaner and more accurate method for json data:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73632045/12645793

Comment: updated but it still not  sending data to api

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you **stringify** the nested **students** array. As you already defined that you accepts the `Students` class as parameter of the `Action`. And inside that `Students` class you mention `List<Student>`

**Resolution:** `stringify` the main object not the nested objects.

**Replace**

```
data: JSON.stringify(oStudent.students)
```

**With**

```
data: JSON.stringify(oStudent)
```

**Ajax Call (Text Data)**

[image: Ajax Call]

**Action Method**

[image: Action Method]